# Why isn't the size of GradientDrawable changing?

Tags: java, android, drawable

I'm trying to change the size of GradientDrawable (used as a background drawable for Button) by using setSize() method, but nothing happens: drawable still has the same size. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found the solution: use setBounds() method instead.